# What is the best practice to work in unmanaged programming pattern

Tags: sql, database, programming-languages, constraints

I have a query

```
UPDATE dbo.M_Room
 SET

 //do something
WHERE PK_RoomId= @RoomId AND IsActive=1 AND FK_DepartmentId =@DepartmentId
```

Now suppose PK_RoomId is my Pk of M_Room and is autoincremented field.
So according to this I could have used

```
WHERE PK_RoomId= @RoomId
```

rather than

```
WHERE PK_RoomId= @RoomId AND IsActive=1 AND FK_DepartmentId =@DepartmentId
```

What all threats I could overcome if I use the second condition rather than 1st one.
If we don't have any relationship/Constraints(PK, FK etc.) physically exists and cant implement due to unmanaged structure of database.

What will be your recommendation in such scenario.
What all things should be done to keep data consistent.

Comment: +1. The question is valid, even if the course of action turns out to be not recommended.

Comment: As long as there is at least one way of putting bad data into the database then you will never solve this problem. You must go through the pain of cleaning up the database.

Comment: @adolf: you cannot implement good practices when working under some organization. You have to follow the guidelines given. Due to these reasons Companies usually earn lifetime maintainence charges from client because of bad coding practices done.

Comment: You *can* implement good practices in any organisation. Too many people throw their hands up in the air and give up. Subtle persistence is usually the key.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to change the `WHERE` to just `WHERE PK_RoomId= @RoomId`. The first part (the part you want to keep) is for identifying the record. The second part (`AND IsActive=1`) is used to maybe restrict the update based on whether the room is active or not. About the last part (`AND FK_DepartmentId =@DepartmentId`), that could mean that sometimes you only want to update the room if it belongs to the department you specified. This could also be useful.

Why exactly would you want to change the query?

Comment: IsActive here refers to pertain a deleted data which is deleted by user and should not go live once became inactive. comparison between department is being done to ensure that current room belongs to given department. All these values are coming for this department although. UI displays only department specific rooms  only and the some operation is performed on it. So should i use department check over here also being known that this room will be of same department for which i m checking

Comment: That's correct, if you can be sure the departmentid will be valid you don't have to check on it in the query anymore. And also, if you can be sure the room will always be active it this query is run than that check can also be removed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using READ-UNCOMMITTED transactions or no transactions at all, or the data has been sitting round on someone's screen for a long time, the additional conditions could save you from a buried update, presuming that your // do something does something to the IsActive column.

It could also be a final guard against just getting it wrong (seeing if the room isn't active and then forgetting to make use of the fact).

Make sure to check the number of rows updated in either case.

Your second-last paragraph suggests the room_id may not be unique when it is supposed to be; you will always have trouble if that's the case.

Myself, I'd be inclined to check explicitly for buried updates if I suspected they may occur, and I'd think that form of defending against programming errors to be unusual.